# Hyperlink control in Access App

Tags: ms-access, sharepoint-2013, ms-access-2013

I've created a hyperlink control on a form page in an Access 2013 App hosted in SharePoint 2013, and want the text to display the same text ("Print Timesheet") while the actual link itself varies based on the value of a field in the record. This is so that I can link to a separate application using a query string with the individual record ID, which gets the data directly from the azure database and formats it in order to be printed out.

I've tried a macro expression to create the link address that runs "on current" and sets the value of the hyperlink, and also tried a computed column in the table to create the link which I pass to the hyperlink control value. I've set the "Default Display Text" on the hyperlink control to "Print Timesheet" in both cases.

The problem I have is that whichever way I try it, changing the value on the fly like this overrides the default display text of the hyperlink so that it displays the address itself rather than the text I want to display.

Is there any way round this?

Thanks,

Duncan

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure if you got your answers. I was randomly looking on internet and found your query.
I thought the thread [Troubles with Hyperlink control in Access Web App forms](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/office_2013_release-access/troubles-with-hyperlink-control-in-access-web-app/b34f6810-f83e-4acf-a634-74fb3d3e0170?auth=1) may have your answer.

> > LILizEidsness replied on  August 21, 2014See post history
>
> .....
>
> If you have to build a url field dynamically, the basic syntax is
>   `displaytext#url#`
>
> so, in my dynamic field....
>   `=Concat("Click here#/relative/path/on/my/sharepointsite/allitems.aspx&ID=",[ID],"#")`
>
> ....

Comment: even if the above link answer the question, you should provide more detail in case the link goes missing.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a label on the form to represent the link.  Have the `Label.Caption` property set to "Print Timesheet" and use the `On Current` event to set the `Label.HyperlinkAddress` property to whatever the address from the recordsource is.

Comment: Thanks, but the label control doesn't appear to have a HyperlinkAddress property for me to set. The only properties available in the SetProperty action are Enabled, Visible, ForeColor, BackColor, Caption and Value. Any thoughts?